# Call a REST end-point from another

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, curl

I have a REST endpoint provided below,

```
    @PutMapping("/calculateReward")
    public ResponseEntity<String> calculateReward(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId) {

        Optional<User> optional = userService.findById(userId);

        if (!optional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
        }

        User user = optional.get();

        double reward = user.getCurrentSteps() * Parameters.REWARD_PER_STEPS_EUR;

        RewardList list = new RewardList();

        list.setUser(user);
        list.setReward(reward);

        user.setCurrentSteps(0);
        user.setRewardLists(list);

        userService.save(user);
        rewardListService.save(list);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        double convertionRateToEuro = currencyMap.get(user.getCurrencyName());
        double rewardConverted = reward * convertionRateToEuro;

        json.put("name", user.getName());
        json.put("currency", user.getCurrencyName());
        json.put("reward", rewardConverted);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(json.toString());
    }
```

ATM I work into another end-point where I need to have the reward value from the end-point provided above.

```
    @PostMapping("/paypal/make/payment")
    public ResponseEntity<String> paymentUsingPaypal(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId) {

        Optional<User> optional = userService.findById(userId);

        if (!optional.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
        }

        User user = optional.get();


        // How do I get the "reward" in double here?
    }
```

How do I get the "reward" in double from the `calculateReward` method in the end of the 2nd method?

Comment: have you tried adding this line? double reward = user.getCurrentSteps() * Parameters.REWARD_PER_STEPS_EUR;

Comment: No, I need to set the current steps to zero as well etc.  Then there is no point of having the `calculateReward ` method which helps in other ways, too.

Comment: If this is a design issue where you don't know how to structure your logic, you need to describe your requirements and the challenges you're facing as well as what you've tried and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same application, why not just calling:

```
nameOfController.calculateReward(userId);
```

If you can't call the method, you would have to write a client using for example [feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign).

Comment: I think this will get the job done `String s = UserAPI.calculateReward(user.getId()).getBody();`

Comment: Great, if you find this answer helpful, consider upvoting / marking as correct;)

Comment: You know, the SO wants us to reflect for several minutes before we can accept an answer ;)

Comment: @Arefe huh, I didn't know that, I haven't been asking lately, thanks;)

Comment: You need to wait like 5-7 minutes to accept an answer. I dont remember this is the case earlier